# son of the leader is flushed out of the undergound city

Tags: story-identification, novel

This book was from the 80's.  The protagonist was the son of the leader of an underground city (the father would always be awake before the alarm).  The kids or maybe everyone had implants that talked into their brains?  There was an uprising, and the son gets flushed out the garbage away from the city and its dome.  He is taken care of by a more primitive but better people who don't have implants.  He learns things about himself and his society's open secrets are exposed to him.  He is bald early on?

I would really like to know what this book was called.  It clearly left an impact.  Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121623/sci-fi-book-90s-or-earlier-societies-on-earth-living-in-domes which is asking about it from the sequel's point of view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Young Adult Science Fiction: Implants, Elite and Slave Classes](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47153/young-adult-science-fiction-implants-elite-and-slave-classes)

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/192684/novel-with-a-class-of-lords-with-external-databank-type-neural-implants (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 5):

I think this could be "Devil on my back" by Monica Hughes, published in 1986. I haven't got a copy with me to confirm, but here is the synopsis from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1190717.Devil_on_My_Back).

I remember they removed all their hair so the "paks" could be put on the back of their necks, and those who didn't want them (or possibly their bodies rejected the paks?) had to work as slaves. The protagonist had to get an upgrade before he would be considered an adult, but the slave uprising interrupted this and he gets outside the city for the first time.

(I will try to find a copy and update this.)